# Google geocode is late (still one step behind)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-geocoder

I put there my whole code. Trying to determine location address. My script should create still one marker with geocoded address (in console - variable kktina).

But, unfortunately, there isn't everything OK. Because by script still resolves previous location (or it takes previous coordinates, dunno). Maybe there is an error in code, but I'm not able to do this anymore..

So asking for help, thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Simple</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
  html, body, #map_canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places,geometry"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
  var map,marker;
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var markers = [];
  var img,icon,type;
  var prenos,pos,address = "5",point;


      function clearMarkersFromArray() {
    if (markers.length>0){
      markers[0].setMap(null);
      markers.shift(markers[0]);
    }
  }

  function geocodePosition(pos) {
    geocoder.geocode({
      latLng: pos
    }, function(responses) {
      if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
        address = responses[0].formatted_address;
      } else {
        address = 'Cannot determine address at this location.';
      }
    });
    return address;
  }

  function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 7,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(49,19),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions),

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(response) {
      clearMarkersFromArray();
      point = new google.maps.LatLng(response.latLng.$a,response.latLng.ab); 
      var kktina = geocodePosition(point);
      console.log(kktina);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: point,
        draggable: true
      });
      markers.push(marker)
      marker.setMap(map);
});
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="height:400px;width:700px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this:

```
  function geocodePosition(pos) {
    geocoder.geocode({
      latLng: pos
    }, function(responses) {
      if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
        address = responses[0].formatted_address;
      } else {
        address = 'Cannot determine address at this location.';
      }
    });
    return address;
  }
```

the Geocoder is asynchronous, the value of address is undefined when it is returned.

Use the returned data inside the callback function instead, something like this (not tested):

```
var kktina = null;
function geocodePosition(pos) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    latLng: pos
  }, function(responses) {
    if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
      kktina = responses[0].formatted_address;
    } else {
      kktina = 'Cannot determine address at this location.';
    }
   console.log(kktina);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: point,
      draggable: true
    });
    markers.push(marker)
    marker.setMap(map);
  });
}
```

Comment: You are right with this. Data must be inside the reponse. But it doesn't work with markers inside /as you written/ (and I also have an InfoWindow, which doesn't work).. :( I would like to fetch - save kktina outside the function.

Comment: If it doesn't work for you as written, fix it, as I said, I didn't test it. It does save kktina in a global variable.  There is no InfoWindow in the code you posted, therefore, this statement "I put there my whole code." is incorrect.